# How to align / count equation labels in Latex

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, labels, format

I am attempting to write a simple equation inside a document that uses Latex, and I have attempting this line of code so far:

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{1.\arabic{equation}\label{}}
\begin{equation}
\begin{center}
$\mathcal{L}= -\frac{1}{4}  \mathcal{F}_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{F}^{\mu \nu} \\
+ \mathcal{i} \overline{\psi} \cancel{D}\psi + h.c. \\
+ \overline{\psi}_i y_{ij} \psi_j \phi + h.c. 
\\
+|D_\mu \phi|^2 - V(\phi)$
\end{equation}
\end{center}
```

This gives me:

[image]

where the label is immediate to the equation.

I have attempted `\setcounter \label \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{align*}`, but to no avail. The equation number continues to be at the very end of this equation, where I would like it to be  right aligned (at the right edge of the page). Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in your code:

- `$...$` and `\[...\]` opens/closes math environments

  - It is the error to use them inside an already created math environments
  - `$...$` is for inline equations (equivalent but preferable form in LaTeX is `\(...\)`)
  - `\[...\]` is a shot form for `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` and is used for quick single-lined equations in display mode without eq. number
- Don't use any form of centring inside math anvironments
- More complex formatting requires other environments e.g. `gather`, `align`, `alignat`

  - Each such environment has an equivalent inner form: `aligned`, `alignedat`, and `gathered`
  - Inner forms can only be used inside already created math environment
  - Each of the inner form produces a single equation number, regardless of a number of lines it contains.

Also, a preferable way to make a section or a chapter number a part of the equation number is to use the following macro defined in `amsmath`:

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

It will reset the equation part every time you start a new section. Change `section` to `chapter` and you will get the same effect with chapters.

Here is one way to format your equation with a single equation number. The `[b]` is an optional argument of `aligned` environment to place eq. number at the bottom of the inner block.

More can be found in the documentation of [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{The first section}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:example}
  \begin{aligned}[b]  % change to [t], [c] if top- or middle-aligned, respectively
    \mathcal{L} &= -\frac{1}{4}  \mathcal{F}_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{F}^{\mu \nu} \\
    &\qquad + \mathcal{i} \overline{\psi} \cancel{D}\psi + h.c. \\
    &\qquad + \overline{\psi}?_i y_{ij} \psi_j \phi + h.c.\\
    &\qquad + |D_\mu \phi|^2 - V(\phi)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Reference to the Equation~\ref{eq:example}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Do not ignore LaTeX errors. They are there for a reason**

In your case, I notice that you have

```
\begin{equation}
   \begin{center}
      ...
   \end{equation}
\end{center}
```

(I added indentation to make it clear what’s happening). You have `\begin{center}` ended with `\end{equation}` and `\begin{equation}` ended with `\end{center}`.

You need to properly nest things.

**And**

you don’t want to use a `center` environment in the first place. And the `$`…`$` shouldn’t be there.

When you have a multiline equation, you should use `split` from the `amsmath` package,¹ so your equation would look like

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \mathcal{L} = … \\
       … \\
       … \\
       …
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

---

1. If you’re unfamiliar with packages, this means that you will want to add to your document’s preamble (the stuff between `\documentclass{…}` and `\begin{document}`), the command:

   ```
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   ```

   You can find out more about the capabilities of the `amsmath` package by typing `texdoc amsmath` at a command line if you're running LaTeX on your computer or going to https://texdoc.org and typing amsmath into the search box there.